# SQL retrieve info

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Table 1

```
(aID, Value)
012 , "hi"
231, "yo"
411, "Be"
```

Table 2

```
(aID, cID)
231 , 012
411, 231
```

How do I retrieve a SQL Select table from table 2 and 1 that will show (aID, aID_Value, cID, c_Value) - So an example of how I want to retrieve data.

```
(231, "yo", 012, "hi")
(411, "Be", 231, "Yo")
```

I have tried

```
SELECT 1.aID, 1.Value, 2.cID, 1.Value
FROM 1 JOIN
     2
     ON 1.aID = 2.cID;
```

But the last 1.Value doesnt match the cID Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `table1` twice to `table2`:

```
select 
  t2.aid, ta.value, t2.cid, tb.value
from table2 t2 
inner join table1 ta on ta.aid = t2.aid
inner join table1 tb on tb.aid = t2.cid
```

These 2 joins will fetch 2 values from the column `value` of table `table1`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rgRaytACJqR5BoZTT1qstP/0)

Comment: tb.value give me unknown column in field list and if i remove it from select then its an empty set

Comment: What is the name of the column? Isn't it value?